# Split string com vírgula como delimitação no Serial.read() do Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C# com Visual Studio que envia um caractere para o Arduino só que agora quero enviar uma string com esta estrutura caractere, número como no exemplo abaixo:

`A,0` ou `R,30` ou `L,15`

Tenho que realizar o split e pegar os valores separados, um **Caractere** e outro **Inteiro**.

Esse é o código Arduino que tenho até agora:

```
void loop() {

  if (Serial.available()) 
  {  
    caractere = Serial.read();  
  }

  /* AQUI REALIZO O SPLIT */

  if( caractere == 'R')
  {
    Serial.println(caractere);
    giraHorario(VALOR INTEIRO AQUI);
  }
  else if( caractere == 'L')
  {
    Serial.println(caractere);
    giraAntiHorario(VALOR INTEIRO AQUI);
  }
  else if(caractere == 'A')
  {
    Serial.println(caractere);
    giraAlternado(VALOR INTEIRO AQUI);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função [`Serial.parseInt`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ParseInt) e então chegar nisso:

```
void gira(char direcao, long valor) {
  if (caractere == 'R') {
    giraHorario(valor);
  } else if (caractere == 'L') {
    giraAntiHorario(valor);
  } else if (caractere == 'A') {
    giraAlternado(valor);
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {  
    char caractere = Serial.read();
    Serial.read(); /* Para ler a vírgula. */
    long valor = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.println(caractere);
    Serial.println(valor);
    gira(caractere, valor);
  }
}
```